# How can I add a dollar sign to link and node labels?

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, htmlwidgets, networkd3

I want to add a dollar sign to the link and node labels in a networkD3 Sankey plot.  A similar question has be asked and answered here:

[Link value label thousands separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55577560/r-networkd3-sankeynetwork-link-value-label-thousands-separator)

In the above link, CJ rewrites the link titles with `htmlwidgets::onRender` to change the thousands separator from "," to ".".

I unfortunately do not understand JavaScript and can not figure out how to change the solution to fit my problem.

EDIT

Trying to apply CJ Yetman's technique to nodes.  My code is not working.

```
customJS <- '
function(el,x) {
    var node = d3.selectAll(".node");

    var format = d3.format("($,.2f");

    node.select("title").select("body")
        .html(function(d) { return "<pre>" + d.target.name + "<br>" + format(d.value) + "<pre>"; });
}
'
```

Suggestions and corrections welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For nodes, you can add "$" to the strings in your data frame before it's passed to `sankeyNetwork()`, like...

```r
nodes <- data.frame(name = c("$a", "$b"))
```

For links, you can adjust the format string ([format specification documented here](https://github.com/d3/d3-format#locale_format)) to whatever you need in the JavaScript command here...

```js
var format = d3.format("$");
```

all together, that looks like this...

```r
library(networkD3)
library(htmlwidgets)

nodes <- data.frame(name = c("$a", "$b"))
links <- data.frame(source = c(0), target = c(1), value = c(12000))

p <- sankeyNetwork(
  Links = links,
  Source = "source",
  Target = "target",
  Value = "value",
  Nodes = nodes,
  NodeID = "name",
  fontSize = 12,
  nodeWidth = 30,
  iterations = 0
)

customJS <- '
function(el,x) { 
    var link = d3.selectAll(".link");

    var format = d3.format("$");

    link.select("title").select("body")
        .html(function(d) { return "<pre>" + d.source.name + " \u2192 " + d.target.name +
            "\\n" + format(d.value) + "<pre>"; });
}
'

onRender(p, customJS)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution CJ Yetman.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using CJ Yetman's code I changed the `var format` to get the format below.

Original     ->      CJ Yetman      ->      My Edit 
12000      ->          $12000        ->               $12,000.00

```
customJS <- '
function(el,x) {
    var link = d3.selectAll(".link");

    var format = d3.format("($,.2f");

    link.select("title").select("body")
        .html(function(d) { return "<pre>" + d.source.name + " \u2192 " + d.target.name +
            "\\n" + format(d.value) + "<pre>"; });
}
'
```

I also used CJ Yetman's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43873498/shiny-networkd3-responding-to-node-click) to use `onRender` to apply the `customJS` in shiny.